# How to Append Horizontal Line in EditText

Tags: android, append

I am attempting to add horizontal line breaks in my chat application but do not know how. Essentially I aim to have the line go across the entire length of the screen as a break so that that users can better read their messages.

For appending the messages I have the code:

```
    if (username != null && message != null) {
        messageHistoryText.append(username + ":\n");
        messageHistoryText.append(message + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
messageHistoryText.setText(username + System.getProperty ("line.separator") + "");
messageHistoryText.setText(message + System.getProperty ("line.separator") + "");
```

Here you just need to concatenate the empty string to your string variable. Hope this works. Just let me know.

Comment: Will this add a horizontal line to the EditText? a line to seperate one string from another like: ___________________________ with text on top and bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
if (username != null && message != null) {
    messageHistoryText.append(username + ":\r\n");
    messageHistoryText.append(message + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Is there a certain style that is required?

Comment: Do you set android:lines, android:minlines or android:maxlines attributes?

Comment: android:lines, android:minlines and android:maxlines are for setting the height of the EditText and TextView, not setting lines..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (username != null && message != null) {
  messageHistoryText.append(username + "|");
  messageHistoryText.append(message + "|");
}
```